# Make target before using it in a $(shell) call

Tags: shell, gnu-make

I have a project that can be configured via a `scenario.xml` file. The project contains a small tool to extract information from this xml file (`tools/xmlq`) which is compiled from a c source file. The Makefiles use this tool to influence the build by assigning its output to various make variables like

```
SOME_VAR := $(shell tools/xmlq some_query)
```

The problem with this approach is that on a clean build, `tools/xmlq` does not exist and `SOME_VAR` will not contain the expected value.

My question is: Is there some way to ensure that make builds `tools/xmlq` before the `$(shell ...)` calls that use it get executed? If not: what workarounds can I use to avoid the problem?

---

Some possible workarounds that I have thought of so far:

1. Use files instead of make variables.

   This means that a construct like

   ```
   SOME_VAR := $(shell tools/xmlq some_query)
   some-target: some-prerequisites
           some-command $(SOME_VAR) $^
   ```

   would change to

   ```
   some-var.txt: tools/xmlq scenario.xml
           $< some_query > $@
   some-target: some-var.txt some-prerequisites
           some-command $$(cat $<) $(filter-out $<,$^)
   ```

   this has the advantage that it feels very idiomatic but has the big disadvantage that I couldn't use e.g. `$(SOME_VAR).o` as a prerequisite any more.
2. Just call `make tools/xmlq` at the start of the makefile with `$(shell make tools/xmlq)`

   (There would obviously have to be some guards to avoid infinite recursion). The disadvantage here would be that the Makefiles are essentially read twice. Once to build `tools/xmlq` and once for the original invokation.

Comment: Is it an option to put a small master makefile as top in the hierarchy, which generates all necessary tools and then recursively calls your current makefile?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that you would have to define every target twice? Once in the current makefile that actually builds it and once in the master makefile to delegate to the current makefile?

Comment: no, just two rules: the 'all' rule which depends on xmlq and your final output file and does a 'make -f oldmakefile.mk' and the xmlq rule, which builds xmlq itself. OTOH the answer below is much better and does not need two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require a workaround, just appropriate `make` logic. In detail
this depends on where the source file `xmlq.c` resides. For illustration
I'll assume it is in `tools`:-

```
SOME_VAR = $(shell tools/xmlq some_query)
some-target: some-prerequisites | tools/xmlq
        some-command $(SOME_VAR) $^

tools/xmlq: tools/xmlq.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ # Or however you build it.
```

There are two points to the solution:-

The immediate assignment

```
SOME_VAR := $(shell tools/xmlq some_query)
```

is replaced with the lazy assigment

```
SOME_VAR = $(shell tools/xmlq some_query)
```

So the definition `$(shell tools/xmlq some_query)` will only be expanded when `$(SOME_VAR)`
is expanded, i.e. when the recipe `some-command $(SOME_VAR) $^` is expanded,
when `make` decides to run it. So `tools/xmlq` need not exist until that momment.

The rule

```
some-target: some-prerequisites | tools/xmlq
```

makes `tools/xmlq` an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
of `some-target`. Which means that `tools/xmlq` will *not* be considered in determining
whether `some-target` should be made, but if it is determined that `some-target` should
be made, then `tools/xmlq` will be made first. Thus `tools/xmlq` will exist before
`make` expands `$(SOME_VAR)`.

A demo:

**tools/xmlq.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        fputs(argv[i],stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: clean foo World

SOME_VAR = $(shell tools/xmlq Hello)
foo: World | tools/xmlq
    echo $(SOME_VAR) $^

tools/xmlq: tools/xmlq.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

World:;

clean:
    rm -fr tools/xmlq.o tools/xmlq
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o tools/xmlq.o tools/xmlq.c
cc -o tools/xmlq tools/xmlq.o
echo Hello World
Hello World
```

And this might be reduced to:

```
.PHONY: clean foo World

foo: World | tools/xmlq
    echo $$(tools/xmlq Hello) $^

tools/xmlq: tools/xmlq.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

World:;

clean:
    rm -fr tools/xmlq.o tools/xmlq
```